# Sphax crashes minecraft on startup

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, sphax-purebdcraft

I'm using Sphax PureBDCraft x256 for 1.7.2, and whenever I load the game it boots the mojang screen and then doesn't respond and I have to close it. However, when I remove Sphax it loads in a couple of seconds. I can still select Sphax from the texture packs menu (when I replace it in the resourcepacks folder) and it loads and fully retextures the game fine. However, the next time the game loads, it continues to crash. How do I fix this?

Comment: Are you using 1.7.2?

Comment: this is stated in the question

Comment: @Caleb Irony. You tried to lecture me on reading the question earlier

Comment: Actually, I was talking about the client version, not the texture pack version, to clarify.

Comment: @Caleb Since I said **for** 1.7.2, it was fairly obvious that I had the 1.7.2 version of sphax and was running the 1.7.2 version of minecraft

Comment: If it was fairly obvious I wouldn't have asked. I asked because using an older resource pack to the client version you are running can cause problems with missing textures and such.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This issue happens with many people and the primary reason for it is that your computer cannot handle x256. When you are changing the resource pack in game it is much less resource intensive. During startup there is a lot more processes occuring and so Sphax will be choking your resources and there won't be enough to load the game - thus the crash.

**Your Options**

1. Use a lower resolution version e.g. x128 or x64 - these versions still look very nice but will use up much less in the way of resources.
2. Assign more ram to your minecraft client - this will give more system resources to minecraft duing play and during startup and by the sounds of it you won't need much more maybe another 512mb. Also try closing all other applications when you open minecraft.
3. The less prefered option - try to remember to change to vanilla before you close and boot the game in vanilla and switch over. I understand this would be a pain but it could be your last resort if your not open to compromising on the resolution of the texture pack and upping your ram doesn;t help.

Comment: Thank you for your help. I had a suspicion that it could be the resolution

Comment: Your welcome in future post your PC specs or at least how much ram you had assigned. I believe on the PUREBD site there is a rough idea of minimum spec but i can't find it myself just now